# Do i need a backflow preventer for drip irrigation system

Tags: plumbing, sprinkler-system, irrigation

A gardener just installed a drip irrigation system in my backyard. He didn't installed the back-flow preventer. When I asked him why, he told me for drip irrigation you don't need the back-flow preventer! His argument was that in drip irrigation, we have to install a pressure reducer so there is no need for a back-flow preventer.

Is he right on his argument?

Comment: The pressure reducing valve has nothing to do with a back flow device. Back flow valves prevent contaminated water from entering the potable household water. A pressure reducing valve doesn't function in this manner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think he is mistaken.  A pressure reducing valve is not listed in the code among the approved backflow prevention devices:

> **2009 Uniform Plumbing Code 603.4.6 Protection From Lawn Sprinklers and Irrigation Systems**
>
> **603.4.6.1**  Potable water supplies to systems having no pumps or connections for pumping equipment, and no chemical injection or
>   provisions for chemical injection, shall be protected from backflow by
>   one of the following devices:
>
> (1) Atmospheric vacuum breaker (2) Pressure vacuum breaker (3)
>   Spill-resistant pressure vacuum breaker (4) Reduced pressure vacuum
>   breaker

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Is Check valve same as Backflow valve? I was trying to see a simplest option which can be installed in the line , but couldn't find one. Any hint are appreciated

Comment: It all depends on what code applies in your jurisdiction.  In many jurisdictions including my own, the UPC applies.  As you can see, a check valve is not listed as an approved device.  In a residential situation an atmospheric vacuum breaker for each zone is often simplest.  In a case with many irrigation zones a single pressure vacuum breaker is used, but they require protection against freezing.

Comment: Is this qualify as a backflow preventer http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FPDEU8?ref_=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_i

Comment: Yes, the example you selected is a typical residential atmospheric vacuum breaker (AVB).  A key point with these is proper installation.  They must be installed after the valve, above ground, usually a minimum of 6" above the highest point downstream of the AVB.

Comment: Thanks Cris, I am not much worried about code, but want to do things which make sense. The Gadner have put  http://www.homedepot.com/p/Rain-Bird-3-4-in-FPT-In-Line-Valve-CP075/202078357. From the description at home depot site it says you might not need the backflow valve.  Am i right on this?

Comment: Hi Chris, One more question, can the backflow prevent http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FPDEU8?ref_=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_i be used in the line feeding the valve. In my house that's the most convenient location of it. Or else i will install it after the sprinkler but that need to be at the farthest end as sprinkler valve are at low end of the grade.

Comment: You should probably consult a licensed plumber in your area.  The RainBird automatic valve you selected has no backflow protection.  An AVB can only be installed after a valve.  A PVB is appropriate for installing before a valve.  Both of these devices occasionally spray water, so they must be outside.

Comment: @David- Yes the link to the amazon backflow is what you want to install on your irrigation line. Install it before the irrigation valves and at least 12" above the highest sprinkler. This anti siphon valve is for irrigation only and not for the main supply line to the house.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that this is for your own safety. It keeps you from drinking water that's been contaminated by nasty things such as animal feces, dead critters, fertilizers, or even pesticides. It keeps you from being sued by your neighbors if they get sick. As it is a law in Texas, even rural areas, we have to abide by it. $100.00 for a PVB with fittings is cheap for the piece of mind.

See:

> §344.50. Backflow Prevention Methods.
>
> (a) Any irrigation system that is connected to a public or private potable water supply must be connected through a commission-approved backflow prevention method. The backflow prevention device must be approved by the American Society of Sanitary Engineers; or the Foundation for Cross-Connection Control and Hydraulic Research, University of Southern California; or the Uniform Plumbing Code;

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it isn't code were you reside it would be wise to install one for your health. But check the valves that you have installed. Many irrigation valve manufacturer's make back flow valves built into them. It's usually just above the out flow threads on the valve. Or if you shake the valve you should hear it rattle. that is the check valve that allows water to only flow in one direction.

Comment: If the Uniform Plumbing Code applies, then a simple back-check will not suffice.  That is also not listed as an approved device.

Answer (score 1):

It is also important to install back-flow preventers to discourage clogging of the drippers. After the irrigation cycle finishes, the volume of the pipe that was full of water will need to be replaced by air or it will collapse at certain points. If there is no 'vacuum breaker' type valve the air will enter the line through the dripper aperture bringing with it dirt and debris. If you want to decrease clogging of drippers and occurrence of dry-spots in the garden, I'd recommend installing such a device at the highest point of each station. If the line is very long, put one every 30 metres or so.